# Scikit-Learn no logging output for transformers in FeatureUnion when n_jobs != 1

Tags: python, logging, scikit-learn

Using a `FeatureUnion` with some custom transformers I noticed that some output wasn't showing up in my terminal that I was expecting from `logger.info()` statements within the transformers. After digging around, I was able to track it down to the `FeatureUnion`'s `n_jobs` parameter. If it is not set to `n_jobs=1` output from `logger`s will not show up. However, output from regular `print()` statements does show up.

#### MWE

```
import logging
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class MyMinMaxScaler(MinMaxScaler):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        logger.info("fitting MyMinMaxScaler")
        print("fitting MyMinMaxScaler")
        super().fit(X, y)


fu = FeatureUnion(
    [("myscaler", MyMinMaxScaler()),
     ("regular_scaler", MinMaxScaler())],
    n_jobs=-1
)

data = np.array([40, 41, 42]).reshape(-1, 1)
fu.fit(data)
logger.info(fu.transform(data))
```

**Output `n_jobs=-1`**

```
fitting MyMinMaxScaler
INFO:__main__:[[0. ]
 [0.5]
 [1. ]]
```

**Output `n_jobs=1`**

```
INFO:__main__:fitting MyMinMaxScaler
fitting MyMinMaxScaler
INFO:__main__:[[0. ]
 [0.5]
 [1. ]]
```

I wonder if this is the intended behavior. I was thinking this may be related to multiprocessing and output from child processes not showing up. But why would regular `print()` statements work as usual and logging output would not?

This behavior, at first, let me believe that my transformers weren't actually being fitted and thus not used at all. It's obviously not a big deal now that I know that the transformers are being used as expected. I would, however, appreciate some insight into why this logging behavior may occur the way it does, and if there is any way around it.

Comment: How are you executing this? From an IDE or in terminal? If from an IDE, you will not get the output. If that ide is in turn started through terminal, then you will get the output on that actual terminal, instead of output space of IDE.

Comment: I execute this in a terminal. I use and IDE only as a code editor.

Comment: Can't reproduce - I see the log output you're not seeing with `n_jobs=-1`. CPython 3.6.3, scikit-learn 0.19.0.

Comment: *Can* reproduce on scikit-learn 0.20.1. Something must have changed between those versions.

Comment: `print(logger)` shows that the logger's level is `WARNING` instead of `INFO` inside `fit`.

Comment: This looks like it *might* have something to do with [loggers being pickled in a way that doesn't save logging configuration](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c81e25586988e5d021673fe7413991191876b144/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py#L866), although I don't see anything that would cause the logger to be pickled.

Comment: Installing `scikit-learn` in a venv and editing the venv's version of `cloudpickle.py` shows that the logger is in fact being pickled, though I'm still not sure why.